# Symfony2: use flush() or persist() to optimize data handling

Tags: php, symfony

Im working with Symfony (const version="2.5.10") and using XAMPP with PHP version of 5.5.19

My problem is I keep on getting out of memory error. Because I think I query thousand of data (rows) in the database. For info, I have a lot of data in the database. I want to use `flush()` or anything that could be use to optimize my data handling.

Here is my code in my indexAction controller:

```
public function indexAction(){
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $po = $em->getRepository('MatrixEdiBundle:EdiTransactionDetail')->findDocs('850');
  return $this->render('MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:index.html.twig', array('po' => $po));
}
```

index.html.twig

```
{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}
{# {% include 'MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:header.html.twig'%} #}
{% block body %}
<div class="content">
</br>
  <table id="datTable"  class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
      <thead>
        <th colspan="8">Edi Matrix</th>
        <tr>
          <th>Po Numbers</th>
          <th>Trading Partner Id</th>
          <th>PO 855 Acknowledgement</th>
          <th>PO 997 Acknowledgement</th>
          <th>Advance Shipment Notice</th>
          <th>Invoice</th>
          <th>Purchase Order Change</th>
          <th>Order Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {% for tran in po %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{ path('matrix_edi_showpo', {'po_num':  tran.poNumber}) }}"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{{tran.poNumber}}</td>

            <td>{{tran.ediTransaction.senderId}}</td>

            <td><a href="{{ path('matrix_edi_findAll', {'po_num':  tran.poNumber, 'sender_id':  tran.ediTransaction.senderId, 'doc_type': 855}) }}"data-toggle="modal"data-target="#myModal">
            {{ render(controller('MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:matrix', {
            'po_num': tran.poNumber, 'sender_id': tran.ediTransaction.senderId, 'reciever_id': tran.    ediTransaction.receiverId, 'doc_type': 855, 'gs_number': tran.ediTransaction.gsNumber })) }}</a>
            </td>

            <td><a href="{{ path('matrix_edi_poack', {'gs_number':  tran.ediTransaction.gsNumber, 'receiver_id':  tran.ediTransaction.receiverId, 'sender_id': tran.ediTransaction.senderId}) }}"data-toggle="modal"data-target="#myModal">
            {{ render(controller('MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:matrix', {
            'po_num': tran.poNumber, 'sender_id': tran.ediTransaction.senderId, 'reciever_id': tran.    ediTransaction.receiverId, 'doc_type': 997, 'gs_number': tran.ediTransaction.gsNumber })) }}</a>
            </td>

            <td><a href="{{ path('matrix_edi_findAll', {'po_num':  tran.poNumber, 'sender_id':  tran.ediTransaction.senderId, 'doc_type': 856}) }}"data-toggle="modal"data-target="#myModal">{{ render(controller('MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:matrix', {
            'po_num': tran.poNumber, 'sender_id': tran.ediTransaction.senderId, 'reciever_id': tran.ediTransaction.receiverId, 'doc_type': 856, 'gs_number': tran.ediTransaction.gsNumber }))}}</a>
            </td>

            <td><a href="{{ path('matrix_edi_findAll', {'po_num':  tran.poNumber, 'sender_id':  tran.ediTransaction.senderId, 'doc_type': 810}) }}"data-toggle="modal"data-target="#myModal">{{ render(controller('MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:matrix', {'po_num': tran.poNumber, 'sender_id': tran.ediTransaction.senderId, 'reciever_id': tran.ediTransaction.receiverId, 'doc_type': 810, 'gs_number': tran.ediTransaction.gsNumber})) }}</a>
            </td>

            <td><a href="{{ path('matrix_edi_findAll', {'po_num':  tran.poNumber, 'sender_id':  tran.ediTransaction.senderId, 'doc_type': 860}) }}"data-toggle="modal"data-target="#myModal">{{ render(controller('MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:matrix', {'po_num': tran.poNumber, 'sender_id': tran.ediTransaction.senderId, 'reciever_id': tran.ediTransaction.receiverId, 'doc_type':860, 'gs_number': tran.ediTransaction.gsNumber})) }}</a>
            </td>

          <td><a href="{{ path('matrix_edi_findAll', {'po_num':  tran.poNumber, 'sender_id':  tran.ediTransaction.senderId, 'doc_type': 870}) }}"data-toggle="modal"data-target="#myModal">{{ render(controller('MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:matrix', {
        'po_num': tran.poNumber, 'sender_id': tran.ediTransaction.senderId, 'reciever_id': tran.ediTransaction.receiverId, 'doc_type': 870, 'gs_number': tran.ediTransaction.gsNumber
    })) }}</a></td>

        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div> 


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width: 650px;">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #2d6ca2; color: white;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true" style="color: white;">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" >Details</h4>
            </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          Loading, please wait......
          <div class="bootstrap-table">

              <div class="fixed-table-container" style="height: 299px; padding-bottom: 37px;">
                <div class="fixed-table-body">
                  <div class="fixed-table-loading" style="top: 27px; display: none;">Loading, please wait…</div>
                </div>
                <div class="fixed-table-pagination"></div>
              </div>
          </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>  

      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
{% javascripts
  'bundles/matrixdoc/js/jQuery.js'
  'bundles/matrixdoc/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'
  'bundles/matrixdoc/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js'
  'bundles/matrixdoc/js/bootstrap.js'
   %}
  <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datTable').dataTable( {
      "scrollY": "400px",
      "scrollCollapse": true,
      "pagingType": "simple",
    });
    $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
      $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
    $(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
      $(e.target).removeData("bs.modal").find(".modal-content").empty();
    });
    });
</script>
{% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do.. `Flush` just saves changes to database, are you trying to fetch thousands of rows or save those objects?

Comment: fetching and maybe save those datas.

Comment: There is something called `Batch proccessing` in Doctrine.. You can get a try, [here is link](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html), But I can't say that `flush` can optimize something..

Comment: i'll just ask,,,, this is this the reason why I got an out of memory error because I fetch a lot of rows in the database? what way could i optimize data handling?

Comment: Can you help me to revise the could so it can't have a out of memory error?

Comment: Post all your code that can be related to your problem. The only answer is really helpful. Why did it not help you?

Comment: that's some heavy code you have here mate render controller for each row and multiple times no wonder your server can't handle it

Comment: how can I optimize it?

Comment: can you give the simpler way it should be but still the same output?

Comment: i will try giving you some help wait a moment

Comment: i'll wait ,,, thanks ahead :)

Comment: hi ,,, do you already have it?

Comment: check and implement it, and give some feedback and don't be impatient mate we are not robots :p

Comment: sorry and thank you .. I'll implement and study this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use pagination getting your data with limits and coupled with partial to get your needed fields if you don't need everything.

http://zrashwani.com/pagination-optimization-symfony2-doctrine/#.VV1av_mSwbg

for partial in DQL , simple example for user:

```
//partial_fields is an array, which can be passed like this $repo->getPartialUser($user_id, array('field1', 'field2', 'etc..');
    public function getPartialUser($id, $partial_fields){
        $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('partial u.{'.implode(',',$partial_fields).'}')
            ->from('AcmeUserBundle:User', 'u')
            ->where('u.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $id);
        $result = $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
        return $result;
    }
```

## EDIT EXAMPLE CODE :

i will give you an example but you will probably still need to adapt it to your code or maybe it will work out of the box.

First  you need a new twig with simple piece of code to show pages numbers for navigation below the table (note that i will not use datatables paginator but we will keep it for table layout rendering) :

## pager.html.twig

```
<div class="pagination">
    <div class="pagination-buttons">
        {% if pagination.page>1 %}
            <a href="{{ path(pagination.route,
            pagination.route_params|merge({'page': 1})) }}"><<</a>
            <a href="{{ path(pagination.route,
            pagination.route_params|merge({'page': pagination.page-1})) }}"><</a>
        {% endif %}
        {#display p numbers only from p-4 to p+4 but don't go <1 or >pages_count#}
        {% for p in range(max(pagination.page-4, 1),
        min(pagination.page+4, pagination.pages_count)) %}
            <a{% if p == pagination.page %} class="current-page"{% endif %}
                    href="{{ path(pagination.route,
                    pagination.route_params|merge({'page': p})) }}">{{ p }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if pagination.page<pagination.pages_count %}
            <a href="{{ path(pagination.route,
            pagination.route_params|merge({'page': pagination.page+1})) }}">></a>
            <a href="{{ path(pagination.route,
            pagination.route_params|merge({'page': pagination.pages_count})) }}">>></a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

## EdiTransactionDetailRepository:

add a function with your field that you use in your table :

```
public function  getPagedDocs($page = 1, $limit = 50)
    {
        $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
             ->select('partial d.{field1,field2 , etc..},
                       partial et.{field1,field2, etc..}'
              ))//select doc fields and second partial for your join select edittransaction fields if you have other joins add another partial etc.. 
             ->from('YourBundle:DocsEntity', 'd')
             ->innerJoin('d.ediTransaction', 'et')//not sure which join you need i have no clue but i believe you will want an inner one since you will want a doc to have a ediTransaction because i didn't see any checks in your twig for it if null.
             ->setFirstResult(($page - 1) * $limit)
             ->setMaxResults($limit);

        $paginator =  new Paginator($qb, $fetchJoinCollection = false);//for more performance fetchjoincollection to false if you have joined tables
        $paginator->setUseOutputWalkers(false);//for more performance set to false for more information http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2890

        return $paginator;
    }
```

PS: Change limit to how many records you want to show in each page depending on the load of data you have make it lower if it is slow for 50 this is depend on how much data each row have.

Next the indexAction in your controller :

```
public function indexAction($page){
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $po = $em->getRepository('MatrixEdiBundle:EdiTransactionDetail')->getPagedDocs($page, 50);
  $count = $po->count();
  $pagination = array(
        'page' => $page,
        'route' => 'docs_index_route_name', //i dont know which name you have but it should be the route name of this indexAction
        'route_params' => array()
    );
    if ($max_records > 0)
        $pagination['pages_count'] = max(ceil($count / $max_records), 1);
  return $this->render('MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:index.html.twig', array('po' => $po,
  'pagination' => $pagination
    ));
}
```

## Routing:

You need to modify the route of your indexAction as we added a parameter page you need to add it for the route too :

```
index_docs:
    pattern:  /index/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: "YourBundle:Controller:index", page: 1 }
```

NOTE : you will need to change the names and stuff i dont know you controller names and bundles so normally you will only need to add /{page} to the pattern and , page:1 to your _controller config which is the default value.

Last thing to do is your index.html.twig which need to include our pager.html.twig

include this piece of code after you close your table :

```
    {% if po|length > 0  and pagination['pages_count'] is defined and pagination['pages_count'] > 0 %}
        {#---------Pager----------#}
        <div style="text-align:center;">
            {% include 'YourBundle:EntityDoc:pager.html.twig' %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
```

NOTE : The include is the path to the file where you create the pager.html.twig i assume you are familiar with how this works.

So if i didn't forget anything this should work out of the box , it should enhance greatly your performance but i am afraid that your render controller there for each row may still be problematic. But try this solution first and see, it depends what you put inside those controllers.

Comment: In my table I am using data tables . It already have the previous and  next , so it still look like I have my pagination .do you want me to post my code?

Comment: you are not using ajax for the paginator of datatable obviously, because the paginator of datatable now is getting all records which are all loaded already, but to be optimized you will need to get records with ajax for each page, i am not efficient with datatable ajax but post your code i will see what i can do

Comment: what is the use of getDoctrine() and getManager()? what is the difference between getManager() and getEntityManager()?  where can I possibly insert the function that you have given? By the way I am just new to symfony and I want to learn from it.

Comment: public function getEntityManager($name = null)
    {
        trigger_error('getEntityManager is deprecated since Symfony 2.1. Use getManager instead', E_USER_DEPRECATED);

        return $this->getManager($name);
    } it was just in previous version getManager in newer versions of symfony , deprecated functions usually call the newer function version as you can see above, until it gets completely deleted later. for datatables you can use this bundle seems quiet reliable or you can get inspired by it and use your own coding it shouldn't be hard to make the ajax work ;) lot of docs on the net

Comment: hi, what do I need to put in the $count = $entities->count(); ? Do i need to change the $entities?

Comment: its updated normally its the returned entities from the query in this case its the $po variable, btw you should use better naming for your variables :p $po->count();

Comment: okay,thanks for the advise... :) I got another question, what should I put in the select partial is it the fields that I already mapped on the ediTransactionDetail and the second is from the ediTransaction?

Comment: for partial d.{ fields... } its the field for your docs that you need in your twig, for partial.et.{ fields...} its the fields for your ediTransaction that you need in your twig because the partial is getting only what you request not all the informations, so if you forget a field in the partial you will not see it in the twig

Comment: for example : in your twig you have {{tran.poNumber}} if in the partial you have partial d.{'id'} you will not see the poNumber in the twig because it is null , you didnt request it from database you request only id, but if you do d.{'id', 'poNumber'} it will show

Comment: what about the max_records?

Comment: put it to the records you want to limit your pager to $max_records = 50; use 50 is ok you can change it depending on how fast the pages load.

Comment: okay,,, what does is error means "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("LIMIT argument offset=-50 is not valid") in MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:index.html.twig at line 15."

Comment: getPagedDocs($page, 50); apparently here you pass -50 not 50 or not?

Comment: what I mean is how can I solve it,all seems okay ,,,, I set my $max_records = 50 like what you said.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78498/discussion-between-nawfal-serrar-and-xammeil).

Comment: that exactly how may code looks like... $po = $em->getRepository('MatrixEdiBundle:EdiTransactionDetail')->getPagedDocs($page, 50);

Comment: i follow your code  and , I would just like to ask if how could I embed it with  pagination that have design?

Comment: hey, I got also the same error like "aizele" ,,, what to do if argument offset = -50?

Comment: Partial is not mandatory but it enhance performances to select only what you need as information, for the offset you control it so it will never be -50